# Excel VBA boolean help needed

Tags: excel

I need a help.

### I have a Function

```
Function Function_EditableOn() As Boolean

End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

if Function_EditableOn = True Then
msgbox("Work")
End if

End Sub
```

I want to do a boolean download from "Function_EditableOn" so that if it equals true then in Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange
you will be able to perform some functions, for example, an inscription will appear

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your function does nothing right now, it will return always false. Try declaring a public variable as Boolean and assign a true/false value as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I made some amendments to your code.

```
Function EditableOn() As Boolean
    EditableOn = True
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        If EditableOn = True Then
            MsgBox "Work"
        End if
    End If
End Sub
```

Save the Event procedure to the code module of any worksheet. You can save the function `EditableOn` to the same module or to a standard code module.

Now, when you click on A1 of the worksheet in whose code module you pasted the event procedure the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event will occur and the procedure by that name will fire. In fact, that event will occur on every click, anywhere in the sheet, and the procedure will run every time but nothing will be done because the proc compares the address of the click (`Target`) with the address of A1 and skip all that don't match.

Since you clicked on A1 the criterium is met and the event procedure will call the function `EditableOn`. That function does nothing. Maybe in the future you will let it download something from the internet and return `True` only if the download was successful. For now, the function just returns `True`. It can't return anything else (for now). Therefore the event procedure will show a MsgBox with the message "Work". This will happen every time you click on A1 except that you can't click on A1 more than once in a row. Select another cell in between.